# Preg Replace Delimiter

Tags: php, regex, delimiter

I have this code:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url = preg_replace("page=[\d]+","",$url);
```

I have a link like this: `http://localhost/search?q=WORD+FOR+SEARCH&page=4`

I'm trying to get that URL then to remove &page=. I never worked with regex for patterns. That's my code. Can someone help me ? Thank you !

This is the error I get when I try to execute that code:

> preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: You need to have a delimiter at the start and end of the regex. See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. The `\d` also doesn't need to be in a character class, can just be `\d+`.

Comment: Thank you @chris85 ! That solved my question !